# EntityFramework Core cache data in memory keeping async operations

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a working app utilizing EF Core 3.0 (preview 8 right now). There's one data set that changes very infrequently, but is queried very frequently. The services that actually perform operations on the data are isolated via a very simple interface.

```
interface IDataProvider
{
    ValueTask<IQueryable<DataRow>> GetDataAsync();
}
```

Until now, there was only one implementation of the data provider built upon an actual SQL database. So if we have a DbContext with `DbSet<DataRow> Data`:

```
class LiveDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly DataDbContext _dbContext;

    public LiveDataProvider(DataDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public ValueTask<IQueryable<DataRow>> GetDataAsync() => 
        new ValueTask<IQueryable<DataRow>>(_dbContext.Data.AsNoTracking());
}
```

Now I'm tasked with adding caching to this application. So the idea is to store the entire `Data` set in-memory, because retrieving it is a fairly expensive query on the DB, but the amount of data is just a few hundred MB. Since updates are infrequent, the vast majority of request would hit the cache. With this idea, the implementation seemed fairly simple:

```
class InMemoryDataCache : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly IPicksDbContext _picksDbContext;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public async ValueTask<IQueryable<DataRow>> GetDataAsync()
    {
        var entryKey = GetEntryKey(); // Implementation is irrelevant.

        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(entryKey, out IQueryable<DataRow> data))
        {
            data = (await _dbContext.Data.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()).AsQueryable();
            _memoryCache.Set(entryKey, data);
        }

        return data;
    }

    InMemoryDataCache(DataDbContext dbContext, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
}
```

Sounds good, doesn't work - the service implementations use asynchronous operations on the `IQueryable` extensively, so `ToListAsync()`, `AnyAsync()` etc. Calling any of these on the cached `List` will results in EF Core throwing an `InvalidOperationException` with message `Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.`

That error is pretty familiar, as unit testing the services threw the same thing. There I mocked an `IAsyncQueryProvider` implementation (shout-out to [MockQueryable](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable)), so here I could the same thing.

Alternatively, I could write my own extension methods for `ToListAsync`, `AnyAsync`, etc. with an implementation of

```
public static Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    if(queryable is IAsyncEnumerable<T>)
    {
        return Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(queryable);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(queryable.ToList());
}
```

Both are a lot of work and tests for something so stupidly simple. Is there a more robust solution? Or have I chased myself into a corner by tying my services to the EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions in the first place and I cannot transparently use an in-memory provider.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a leaky abstraction. I might agree with your assessment of the tight coupling to EF concerns.

Comment: Take a look at the following EF Core extension - [EFSecondLevelCache.Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#efsecondlevelcachecore)